# Clarification on order element calculation

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

> Calculate the order of the element
>
> (4,9) in $Z_{18}$ X $Z_{18}$

I am trying to understand how to calculate this.

There is a post that explains and gives an answer of 18. 
[Calculating the order of an element in group theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584021/calculating-the-order-of-an-element-in-group-theory)

However, this answer differs from the correct answer in the book which is $24$. So now I am confused on how to do this. Any help?

*PS: this is not hw, I am test prepping.*

Comment: 18 is correct; 24 is wrong. To check it, add $(4,9)$ to itself 24 times and see that you don't get $(0,0)$ modulo 18. Unless I messed up the arithmetic, you get $(6,0)$ modulo 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to any: Find the order of $(a,b)$ in $$\mathbb{Z}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}_n$$ is to calculate the order of $a$ and $b$ in their respective groups and then consider their lowest common multiple. In fact if $c$ and $d$ are respectively order of $a$ and $b$, then $\operatorname{lcm}(c,d)=e$ is the smallest positive integer for which $$e(a,b)=(a,b)+\dotsb +(a,b)=(ea,eb)=(0,0).$$

In this case the order of $4$ is $9$, and the order of $9$ is $2$, so the answer is $18$